# Finding Diffie-Hellman secret key with only some know values

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I currently have the following information and I assume the first line separated by the: represents the prime number and generator. Is there any way I can find the secret key shared for the Diffie-Hellman key exchange with only this information?

43223423423:34234234242443423423

- Alice's Public:OTEONZJTYZTOCTMETYDMQNMNCDNIOEIMDYAXYOTD
- Bob's Public: NDGZZNZGYNZNMJOEMCNITNATNIMQJKNTZZEMJDA

Comment: why the original values were deleted?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3):

You have

- $p = 1219113036371115975795111736303119121$ a 120-bit prime number;
- $g = 17746761831$ the generator;
- $A = 929974118015962407341632575868523814$, Alice's public number;
- $B = 798434686913373724514707188622048606$, Bob's public number.

Note: the values $A$ and $B$ are integers viewed in a decimal string, and then base64 encoded.
So beware when converting back as an integer.

There exists $a$ and $b$ such that $A = g^a$ and $B = g^b$ and the shared Diffie-Hellman secret is $S = g^{ab}$.

To find $a$ (or $b$), it is necessary to solve a discrete logarithm.
The factorization of $p-1$ is
$$
p - 1 = 2^4 \cdot3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 130247119270418373482383732511017
$$
where the largest prime factor is a 107-bit prime number.
Generic algorithms (Pohlig-Hellman followed by Pollard's rho algorithms) can solve it in time complexity $O(2^{53.5})$, but there exist better methods for this case.

For instance, the largest record for a discrete logarithm problem in this context is for a 795-bit prime number as you can see on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records#Integers_modulo_p).

So this very doable with the right tools.
There is [CADO-NFS](http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/) but I am not sure it has the right parameters for this prime number.

Comment: Note that let $q= 130247119270418373482383732511017$ then $g^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$

Comment: Won't you correct this answer? Pohlig-Hellman is not necessary here.